# Forcing conda to update package without downgrading others, ignoring any possible bad side effects

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, package-managers

Trying to update conda gives

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  prompt_toolkit                                2.0.10-py_0 --> 3.0.0-py_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  jupyter_console                              6.0.0-py37_0 --> 5.2.0-py37_1
```

Let's say I want to update `prompt_toolkit` without downgrading `jupyter`.  I understand that if `jupyter-console` needs `prompt_toolkit`< 3.0 I could have a bad time, but what if I want to take that risk?

Is there a command like `conda update prompt_toolkit=3.0.0-py_0 --only-look-at-this`, where conda will just blindly install `prompt_toolkit` without even looking at things that depend on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the conda update [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/update.html):

> **--no-deps**
>
> Do not install, update, remove, or change dependencies. This WILL lead to broken environments and inconsistent behavior. Use at your own risk.

Alternatively, if you want to install new dependencies, but not change ones that are already installed:

> **--freeze-installed, --no-update-deps**
>
> Do not update or change already-installed dependencies.