# How to diagnose a conda install that forces downgrade of other packages?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

I tried to use Anaconda to install `Pandas`. However, as part of doing so, `conda` forcibly downgraded other unrelated packages, such as `TensorFlow` and `Numpy`. `Pandas` eventually installed with version 1.2.4.

I don't want these other packages to be downgraded. **How do I diagnose this problem?** Is the problem with Pandas, conda, or the conda package server?

```
> conda install pandas

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    h5py-2.10.0                |   py39hec9cf62_0         1.1 MB
    intel-openmp-2020.2        |              254         947 KB
    mkl-2020.2                 |              256       213.9 MB
    mkl-service-2.3.0          |   py39he8ac12f_0          58 KB
    mkl_fft-1.3.0              |   py39h54f3939_0         195 KB
    mkl_random-1.0.2           |   py39h63df603_0         379 KB
    numpy-1.19.2               |   py39h89c1606_0          21 KB
    numpy-base-1.19.2          |   py39h2ae0177_0         5.3 MB
    pandas-1.2.4               |   py39h2531618_0        11.4 MB
    python-dateutil-2.8.2      |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         241 KB
    pytz-2021.1                |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         244 KB
    scipy-1.6.2                |   py39h91f5cce_0        20.6 MB
    tensorflow-2.4.1           |mkl_py39h4683426_0           3 KB
    tensorflow-base-2.4.1      |mkl_py39h43e0292_0       125.5 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       379.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  pandas             pkgs/main/linux-64::pandas-1.2.4-py39h2531618_0
  python-dateutil    pkgs/main/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pytz               pkgs/main/noarch::pytz-2021.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  h5py                                 3.2.1-py39h6c542dc_0 --> 2.10.0-py39hec9cf62_0
  intel-openmp                       2021.3.0-h06a4308_3350 --> 2020.2-254
  mkl                                 2021.3.0-h06a4308_520 --> 2020.2-256
  mkl-service                          2.4.0-py39h7f8727e_0 --> 2.3.0-py39he8ac12f_0
  mkl_fft                              1.3.0-py39h42c9631_2 --> 1.3.0-py39h54f3939_0
  mkl_random                           1.2.2-py39h51133e4_0 --> 1.0.2-py39h63df603_0
  numpy                               1.20.3-py39hf144106_0 --> 1.19.2-py39h89c1606_0
  numpy-base                          1.20.3-py39h74d4b33_0 --> 1.19.2-py39h2ae0177_0
  scipy                                1.6.2-py39had2a1c9_1 --> 1.6.2-py39h91f5cce_0
  tensorflow                       2.5.0-mkl_py39h4a0693c_0 --> 2.4.1-mkl_py39h4683426_0
  tensorflow-base                  2.5.0-mkl_py39h35b2a3d_0 --> 2.4.1-mkl_py39h43e0292_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forcing conda to update package without downgrading others, ignoring any possible bad side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142547/forcing-conda-to-update-package-without-downgrading-others-ignoring-any-possibl)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I'm trying to diagnose where the problem is at.

Comment: My question clearly asked: `How do I diagnose this problem?` Did you read it?

Comment: you can use `conda search <package>=<version>=<build> --search` to check the exact requirements of pandas and then try to traverse from there.

Comment: sorry, meant `--info`

Comment: Could you please share the explicit specifications that are active in this environment? `conda env export --from-history` I can attest that co-installing `pandas=1.2.4 python=3.9 tensorflow` leads to installing all the newest versions (not the downgraded versions), so I suspect there is something else constraining the environment.